# Not getting ForeignKey value after Model.Form.save

Tags: python, django, orm, foreign-keys

I have the following attribute in my table `Project`

```
sales_person = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, related_name='ad_sales_person', editable=False,null=True, blank=True)
```

I have a Model form like this.

```
class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
 exclude = ('created_by', 'current_user', 'project_current_state')


 def save(self, request=None, commit=False):
        project = super(ProjectForm, self).save(commit=commit)
        project.sales_person_id = project.customer.created_by.id
        project.save()
        project.sales_person # I should get the User object here. But i am not getting it here?
```

I want to get the `sales_person` object after i save the model object. What I am not doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, assigning of the `*_id` field do not load corresponding model instance.  So you should load the instance manually:

```
project.save()
project.sales_person = MyUser.objects.get(pk=project.sales_person_id)
```

But why you don't assign a `MyUser` instance to the field?  This will not add any performance penalty:

```
project.sales_person = project.customer.created_by
```

Comment: The second option makes more sense. But not sure why not after the instance is saved; to the model and we can access that salesman instance by querying the DB but the current model object is not reflecting the change. Strange

Comment: This is not strange. When you manipulate the `*_id` field you deliberately bypass the django code that handles the `ForeignKey` property of the instance.